# How do I update multiple tables using prepared statements with mySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a form with two fields with the name attribute of 'photo_title' and 'photographer_name', and a hidden field named 'photo_id'. When the user pushes the submit button, i want it to update two separate tables in the database. I can get it to update a single table, but as soon as I try to leftjoin the second table, it doesn't like it.

I think there may be something wrong with my query string or the binding. How can I update two separate values in two separate tables in my Mysql database while still using prepared statements?

Here's the PHP:

```
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) { 

$sql = 'UPDATE photos SET photos.photo_title = ?, photographers.photographer_name = ?
    LEFT JOIN photographers ON photos.photographer_id = photographers.photographer_id
    WHERE photo_id = ?';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $_POST['photo_title'], $_POST['photographer_name'], $_POST['photo_id']);       
    $done = $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Here's the form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <input name="photo_title" type="text" value=""/>
   <textarea name="photographer_name"></textarea>

   <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update entry" />
   <input name="photo_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $photo_id ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I figured out my mistake. I had the SQL commands in the wrong order. The query string should have read 

$sql = 'UPDATE photos 
    LEFT JOIN photographers 
    ON photos.photographer_id = photographers.photographer_id
    SET photos.photo_title = ?, photographers.photographer_name = ?
    WHERE photos.photo_id = ?';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer so folks who read this question see it, instead of finding it in your comment above.  I'll mark this CW so I don't get any points for it.

```
UPDATE photos LEFT JOIN photographers 
  ON photos.photographer_id = photographers.photographer_id 
SET photos.photo_title = ?, photographers.photographer_name = ? 
WHERE photos.photo_id = ?
```

FWIW, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) for MySQL's UPDATE syntax is illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on something similar. Here is a few things that I did. Hope it helps

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id=intval($_GET['photo_id']);
    $photo_title=$_POST['photo_title'];
    $photographer_name=$_POST['photographer_name'];

    $sql = "update photos p, photographers pg set p.photo_title=:photo_title, pg.photographer_name=:photographer_name where p.photographer_id=$id and pg.photographer_id=$id";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':photo_title',$photo_title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':photographer_name',$photographer_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}
```

You can even add your photo_id to the form action in case you want to use the id on a different page.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php?id=<?php echo $photo_id;?>">
    <input name="photo_title" type="text" value=""/>
    <textarea name="photographer_name"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update entry" />
</form>
```

I have a file I created that connects to the database that I named config that has the following codes. Include it with this code  where your form is at the top so you don't get errors executing the code above.

```
<?php
    // DB credentials.
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASS','');
    define('DB_NAME','photographer');
    // Establish database connection.
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, 
        DB_PASS,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
        }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());}
?>
```